# How to disable 'sort_by' in a One2many tree view

Tags: listview, odoo, many-to-one, odoo-12

What I want is simple, but I have no idea how to do it, I would be glad if anyone could help me
So I have this One2many tree view :
[image: One2many tree view]

For this model :

```
class StockInventoryDeGroupeLine(models.Model):
    
        _name = 'stock.inventory.degroupe.line'
        _order = 'sequence'
    
        stock_inventory_id = fields.Many2one(
            'stock.inventory',
            string='stock',
        )
        product_id = fields.Many2one(
            'product.product',
            string='Article',
        )
        quantity = fields.Float(
            string='Quantité',
        )
        display_type = fields.Selection([
            ('line_section', "Section"),
            ('line_emplacement', "Emplacement"),
            ('line_note', "Note"),],
            default=False,
            help="Technical field for UX purpose.")
        name = fields.Text(
            string='Description',
            required=False,
        )
        sequence = fields.Integer(
            string='Sequence',
            default=10,  
        )
        location_id = fields.Many2one(
            'stock.location',
            string='Emplacement',
        )
        prod_lot_id = fields.Many2one(
              'stock.production.lot', 
              'Lot/numéro de sérié',
               )
        product_tracking = fields.Selection(
            'Suivi', 
            related='product_id.tracking', 
            readonly=True)
    
        _sql_constraints = [('unique_seq','UNIQUE(sequence)',"La sequence doit être unique"),]
      
    
    
        @api.onchange('product_id', 'sequence')
        def onchange_product_id(self):
            for record in self:
                if record.display_type == False or record.display_type == 'line_emplacement' :
                    if record.sequence == 10 :
                        record.location_id = record.stock_inventory_id.location_id
                        return
                    else :
                        new_sequence = record.sequence -1
                        while new_sequence >= 10 :
                            for record2 in record.stock_inventory_id.degroupee_line_ids :
                                if record2.sequence == new_sequence :
                                    if record2.display_type != 'line_section':
                                        record.location_id = record2.location_id
                                        return
                            new_sequence -= 1
                
        @api.onchange('product_id','location_id','name')
        def onchange_sequence(self):
            for record in self :
                record.sequence += 1
```

When I'm in the editing mode, I want to disable sort by article, lot, emplacement...
To make it simple, I want to have it sorted only by sequence

Comment: I think your field is not many2one and it is one2many field and the record are sorty by with the record you create latest will be in last record.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake i fixed it ,, when i sort by 'Article' then try to add a new record  it's messing with my function

Comment: I am confused. Tell me what exactly you want to do and what you need.I think I can help you

Comment: You got error in your function? You have two function and which function is messing?Which error?

Comment: When i add a new 'Article' ,it takes the 'Emplacement' of the previous line or the default 'Emplacement' as you can see in the 'onchange' function...but if i sort by 'Article' then add a new line it takes the default 'Emplacement'

Comment: I see your emplacement fields has no default function and in your onchange method, you have two condition for assigning for emplacement and that is depend on your sequence.You mean if case is default emplacement assignment?

Comment: actually  'Emplacement' takes by default the 'Emplacement' of the current view form 'stock.inventory' ,,,and the actual problem is with the sequence ,if i sort my fields and add a new line it takes the default sequence" 10 "

Answer (score 1):

may be it will hepls you...

put your sequence field in one2many tree view as invisible..